# How to find unknown keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

A few times its happened to me that I tried to set a keyboard shortcut using Ubuntu's keyboard GUI, there was no error provided for me, but the shortcut just didn't work. I assume this is because there is some other shortcut which is interfering with the one I want to set though I don't see anything listed in the shortcuts. Is there a way to find out what a keyboard combination is doing?

In my particular case I'm currently trying to set the key combination  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd> on Ubuntu 18.04.

**Edit:** I realized the problem is a little more subtle. I have capslock acting as ctrl and the shortcut I created only doesn't work when I try to use my capslock as ctrl (note that other shortcuts I've made do work using capslock as ctrl,e.g. I've made a shortcut for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> which works just as desired.

Comment: What command you set as shortcut in the first place ? You may have an error in the command

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy - the command is correct. I've tried several different ones to check this (including e.g., just `evince` as a test)